# Type constraints on the companion object of a type parameter in scala

Tags: scala

I would like to define a parameterized class called ExtendedNumber which would take some form of whole number such as Int or Byte and extend it so as to include infinity, -infinity and null.  In particular, I'd like to use MaxValue to represent infinity.  If MaxValue was a static member, I believe I could do something like this:

```
class ExtendedNumber[T <: {val MaxValue : T}] {
  val infinity = T.MaxValue
  ...
}
```

However, since MaxValue is defined in the companion object, I believe I need to put a type constraint on the companion object.  Is this possible?  I'm also open to other solutions of the general problem.

Comment: I don't believe you can directly constrain a companion object since companions are not really a part of the type system but rather a relaxation of the access rules when certain lexical relationship holds between a class and an object. Companions are also reflected in the implicit resolution rules and it's conceivable, I guess, that you could hook in to that somehow. But I'd look at using a context bound to convey the value bearing the `infinity`, `-infinity` etc. values (possibly a zero, as well) to `ExtendedNumber`.

Answer (score 3):

The general solution is to add a type class, for example:

```
trait ExtendedNumber[T] {
  def infinity: T
}

implicit object extendedInt extends ExtendedNumber[Int] {
  def infinity = Int.MaxValue
}

def foo[T](v: T)(implicit en: ExtendedNumber[T]) = v == en.infinity
```